# Apache Storm bolts stops receiving tuples after recovery

Tags: apache-storm

Topology consists of a spout(S) and several bolts(B1, B2, B3).
Topology scheme looks like this: S->B1->B2->B3.
 
2 workers are used to run the topology.
Once in a while corrupted data comes into topology that causes bolt B1 to crash. Storm recovers affected worker process and restarts bolt B1. But after that bolt B1 doesn't receive any tuples from the spout. With a debug mode I was able to see in workers logs that spout actually sends tuples but bolt B1 never seems to receive and process them. 
Nimbus.log and supervisor.log shows no errors and Storm assigns work to a recovered worker.


With 1 worker recovery process works well and bolt receives tuples after recovery.

My setup: 
- Apache Storm 0.9.2
 
- Zookeeper 3.4.5
- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: Did you get an exception stack trace in your bolt? Storm-ui should have catched it.

Comment: I do have stack trace for the exception caused by corrupted data. It is related to business logic and it happens inside bolt. This exception causes Async loop to die and Storm restarts the worker. There are no more other exceptions in the log.

Comment: @devbox Did you get to the bottom of this? I have a very similar issue where a failed task is re-created but never tuples that are emitted to it are never received following re-creation.